# Error with the JSON File while using scrapy for crawling

Tags: json, scrapy

I am using a script, [Financial-News-Crawler](https://github.com/rahulrrixe/Financial-News-Crawler), that I found on GitHub using Scrapy. Basically this crawls the mentioned website. It uses a Json file where rules and paths are mentioned for the website to crawl. I had a look at the scrapy documentation in order to write the JSON file for my yahoo finance website. When I try to run the script it says *"No json could be decoded."*

Here is the structure of the .json file:

```
{
    "allowed_domains" : [“finance.yahoo.com”],
    "start_urls": [
        "http://finance.yahoo.com/investing-news/"
    ],
    "rules": [

            {
            "allow": [“/investing-news"],
            "follow": true
        },
    ],
    "paths": {
        "title" : ["//title/text()"],
        "date" : ["//span[@class='datestamp']/text()"],
        "text" : ["//div[@id=‘article_content’]”, "//div[@id='article_body']"]
    },
    "source": “finance yahoo“,
    "company": “Yahoo”
}
```

What am I doing anything wrong?